# Python executable hangs when I call pl.plot in IPython on Mac

Tags: python, macos, ipython

When I run this code in IPython:

[image]

This application icon pops up in my doc and bounces, but it never stops bouncing, and does not respond. I expect the plot to appear in IPython, but it doesn't. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try launching ipython like this:

```
ipython notebook --pylab inline
```

to enable inline pylab plots. Have a look [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jakevdp/matplotlib_pydata2013/blob/master/notebooks/01_Introduction.ipynb) for more information.

ps: you don't need `;` at the end of the line in python

Comment: You are right that the semicolons are not needed. But in the case of an IPython notebook, it can be useful to put one at the end of the `pl.title` line if she wants to prevent the notebook from printing the `<matplotlib.text....` output.

Answer (score 0):

Try launching ipython with the args:

```
ipython notebook --pylab inline
```

That will embed the plot in the notebook session